# How to derive the probability of a singleton if we define the probability of an open set?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the probability space $((0,1],\mathcal{B},P)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra that contains all intervals of the form $(a,b]$ and $P$ is a probability measure such that $P((a,b])=b-a$ for any $(a,b]\in\mathcal{B}$.

How to prove $P(\{x\})=0$ for any $x\in(0,1]$?

Comment: Hint: If $p \geq 0$ and $p \leq \epsilon$ for every positive real $\epsilon$,...

Comment: Continuity of probability measures: If $A_n$ is a sequence of events decreasing to $A$ then $P(A_n) \to P(A)$.

Comment: If $A \subset B$ then $P(A) \le P(B)$.